# MATLAB image processing of a horizon

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to process an image using MATLAB. This is a simple assignment, and I have done almost everything except for one part.

Basically, I have an image of a city horizon. I process the image using [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) and [Canny edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector). Next, there will be many different lines where the edge detection detects lines, and it will draw them. However, I need to plot a new line across the main horizon, using the points given from the edge detection. I have already figured out how to get the first point to draw the line across the true horizon, but I cannot get the second point to draw that line.

It needs to scan the image on the right side, and when it detects a point on the Canny edge detection coordinates, it will store the coordinates and use it as a second point to draw the line. How can I do that?

I believe it is using a simple "for" loop or "ismember", but I am not sure exactly how to do it. For the first coordinate on the left, I used the minimum value in the array, which is easy. But for the second coordinate, what it needs to do is to scan the image on the far right, from top to bottom. And when it detects a coordinate, it will actually store this coordinate, and use it to create the line across the true horizon.

My code is below.

```
    I = imread('Picture9.jpg'); % Input image file here
    dim = size(I); % Get size of the image and store in an array called 'dim'.
    %size array matrix; 1 is height, 2 is width
    height = dim(1);
    width = dim(2);
end

I = rgb2gray(I); % Convert to grayscale
BW = edge(I,'canny',[]); % Edge detection using Canny
imshow(BW);
[H,T,R] = hough(BW);

%  figure, imshow(H,[], 'XData', T, 'YData', R, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit');
%  xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
axis on, axis normal, hold on;
P  = houghpeaks(H,50,'threshold',ceil(0.1*max(H(:))));

% Set houghpeaks parameters, threshold unsure
x = T(P(:,2));
y = R(P(:,1));
plot(x,y,'s','color','white');

% Apply median filtering
I = medfilt2(I);

% Find lines and plot them
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
figure, imshow(I),imagesc(I), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
    xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
    plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

    % plot beginnings and ends of lines
    plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
    plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
end

showlines = struct(lines);
cellData = struct2cell(showlines);

% X-coordinates are for width
% Y-coordinates are for height
%point1(x y) etc
for i = 1:280
    % 'A' stores all 'x' coordinates of point 1
    A([i,i+1])= [cellData{1,i}];
    % 'B' stores all 'x' coordinates of point 2
    B([i,i+1])= [cellData{2,i}];
    % 'C' stores all 'y' coordinates of point 1
    C([i,i])= [cellData{1,i}];
    % 'D' stores all 'y' coordinates of point 2
    D([i,i])= [cellData{2,i}];
end
```

This is the part where I am trying to get the second point to draw the line. But it is wrong. Are there any other methods which are more suitable?

```
for height = 1:dim(1)
    for width = 635:dim(2)
        if X(height,width) == J(D,B)
            newpos = J(C,A);
        end
    end
end

plot( [((min(A)+min(B))/2),max(B)], [((min(C)+min(D))/2),newpos], 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'red');
```

Comment: Can you add the example image you are working with?